# Is the domain of a complex function always open? Is $\mathbb C$\ (the domain) always of measure zero? What if the function is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Usually the domain of a complex function is $\mathbb C\backslash\{z\in\mathbb C~:~z \text{ is a singularity of } f \}$ So I guess it must always be $\mathbb C\backslash\{\text{a set of points}\}$. Moreover it's usually a finite or at most countable set of points.

So the domain doesn't need to be open because it can be the infinite intersection $\bigcap\limits_{i\in A}{}\mathbb C\backslash\{z_i\}$ and $A$ counld be infinite. For instance $\bigcap\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}{}\mathbb C\backslash\{{1\over n}\}$ is not open.

Can the domain be closed?

Is there a complex function that is not defined on a connected set that is more than a segment?

What if $f$ is holomorphic/meromorphic?

Comment: Functions can be defined from any set to any other set. For holomorphic/ meromorphic functions the domain is taken to be open.

Answer (score 0):

First of of all, asserting that the domain of a function $f$ is the complement of the set of singularities of $f$ makes no sense, because it is clearly a circular defintion.

It is just a matter of definition. Often, but not always, , the domain of a holomorphic function is open *by definition*.

On the other hand, if $r\in(0,1]$ and if I define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&D(0,r)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n,\end{array}$$then the domain of $f$ is $D(0,r)$. This has nothing to do with singularities. And, yes, the domain can also be $\overline{D(0,r)}$ (if you are not assuming that the domain is open by definition), unless $r=1$.

Comment: Isn't the domain defined as the set of points for which $f$ is defined? Is there a function that is not defined on a connected set that is more than a segment?

Comment: Concerning your first question, the answer is negative. You must declare which is your domain (and codomain) *first* and only then to declare state what $f$ is.

Comment: Is there a word for the domain of definition? I'm interested in $f$ seen in the biggest possible space

Comment: I suppose that what you have in mind is [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).

Comment: Yes. Is is true that any function can be extended by analytical continuation to almost $\mathbb C$?

Comment: No if, as usual, you assume that the domain is connectd. Consider, for instance, the function $f\colon D(0,1)\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ defined by$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}.$$You cannot extend it (as a holomorphic function) to any larger connected set containing $D(0,1)$. The relevant concept here is that of [natural boundary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalBoundary.html).